# Maintain numpy array data type when reloading data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Say you create a dataframe like this, where one column contains a numpy array:

```
data = {'col_1': [np.array([1,2,3])], 'col_2': 3}

x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Then you write it to csv and (in a different file) import it as a dataframe:

```
filename = 'test.csv'

x.to_csv(filename)

x2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Now when you print the type of the `numpy` array:

`print(type(x2.iloc[0,2]))`

it returns <class 'str'> instead of a numpy array. Is there a way to avoid this and keep the numpy array type, for instance by using Pickle instead of writing to a csv? Or are datatypes always lost when you write a dataframe to a file, then reload it?

Comment: not if you are going to use csv as a format, no there isn't. And yeah, pickle should work. Did you try it?

Comment: csv is a 2d format, rows and columns.  Your array (or lists) adds a 3rd dimension.  It can only write the string version of the array. Look at the csv itself.

Comment: Tried with `x.to_pickle("test.pkl")` then `x3 = pd.read_pickle("test.pkl")`. For printing : `print(type(x3.iloc[0,0]))`  gives me :  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.  Also `x.to_parquet` and `pd.read_parquet` works fine.